# get groups with n smallest sums within column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
   a  b  c
0  A  1  0
1  A  1  1
2  A  1  0
3  A  2  1
4  A  2  1
5  A  2  0
6  A  3  0
7  A  3  0
8  A  3  1
9  A  4  1
10 A  4  1
11 A  4  1
12 B  5  0
```

I want the amount/sum of 1's in 'c' within groups of 'a' and 'b' and keep only the groups within groups of 'a' that have the 2 lowest amounts of 1's. If 2 groups have same amounts of 1's, keep both!! Here, for example, there are 2 groups with one 1 and one group with one 1. In this case all three groups contain to the 2 least amounts of 1's within groups of 'a':

```
   a  b  c
0  A  1  0
1  A  1  1
2  A  1  0
3  A  2  1
4  A  2  1
5  A  2  0
6  A  3  0
7  A  3  0
8  A  3  1 
12 B  5  0
```

I tried with

```
groupby and cumsum()
```

but how can I get the n lowest groups with the 2 lowest amounts of 1's?
Is that understandable?

Comment: Why weren't the last row included in the output?

Comment: You aure right. The row was only to show that there are different groups within 'a'

Comment: I edited it. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try this:

```
df[df.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].transform('sum').groupby(df['a']).rank(method='dense') <= 2]
```

Output:

```
    a  b  c
0   A  1  0
1   A  1  1
2   A  1  0
3   A  2  1
4   A  2  1
5   A  2  0
6   A  3  0
7   A  3  0
8   A  3  1
12  B  5  0
```

#### Explanation

First, create a boolean series by grouping by columns 'a' and 'b' and sum the number from column 'c', then rank those sums based on grouping by column 'a'  then compare the rank to the number n, which is 2 in this case. Fetching all records with a group less than 2, there by fetching all groups of 'a' and 'b' where the sum of 'c' is smallest in each group 'a'.